# Keyboard shortcut between C++ implementation and header files in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Android Studio do develop an Android app that utilizes the NDK and uses C++ files. I was wondering if there is **a keyboard shortcut that allows toggling between the C++ implementation and header files** in Android Studio or another efficient way to go back and forth between the files?

I have looked at https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html and didn't find such a shortcut.

I know it is possible to click on the arrows icon to go to the definition/declaration of a function, but you have to use the mouse and that is not convenient:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key for this is <kbd>F10</kbd> by default.

Comment: Only took 5 years to get this question answered ☺ - thank you @VioletGiraffe